# Use templated object within a templated class with different sets of template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to use a templated object in a templated class where the template parameters of the object are not the same ones needed by the class. It sounds a bit confusing because is not described correctly, here is an example.

The following class implements a binary search tree:

```
template <typename KEY, typename VALUE>
class BST{
  public:
    BST(void){
      cache = new GCACHE<uint64_t, BSTObject>(this);
    }

    struct{
     string value;
    }BSTObject;

    GCACHE<uint64_t, BSTObject>* cache;

    ...
}
```

the GCACHE class implements a generic cache, and to function correctly it needs a pointer to the BST it has to cache. This pointer is passed to the GCACHE constructor:

```
template <typename CKEY, typename OBJECT>
GCACHE{
  public:
   GCACHE( *** pointer to BST, a templated class whoose template types that are not CKEY and OBJECT ***); (A)
}
```

How can I specify/define in (A) a set of template parameters that is different to the one needed by GCACHE (CKEY and OBJECT in the example)?
The template parameters of the GCACHE object are `uint64_t` and `BSTObject` and the template parameters of the BST object might be `int` and `string`.

I'm really confused. Maybe I'm getting it all wrong and the solution is very simple...
thank you for your help.

I hope that the above example is clear enough to obtain help. If not please let me know so that I can rephrase the question.

Comment: The `BST` template defines `BSTObject` as a member object, but you're also trying to use `BSTObject` as a type in the template argument for `GCACHE<uint64_t, BSTObject>`. It's not clear what that's supposed to be.

Comment: Also, how does `BST` actually use its `KEY` and `VALUE` parameters? How does `GCACHE` (thinking of it as a general utility, not in relation to BSTs), use its `CKEY` and `OBJECT` parameters?

Comment: The class BST uses KEY and VALUE in methods insert() find() and delete(). Class GCACHE uses BSTObj to store VALUE object together with cahce related information (hits...)

Answer (score 1):

What parts of `BST` does `GCACHE` need access to?

If it only needs to access parts that don't depend on the template parameters `KEY` and `VALUE`, then create an abstract interface class that `BST` implements, and use that class as the pointer type for the `GCACHE` constructor:

```
class BSTInterface {
    ...
};

template<typename KEY, typename VALUE>
class BST : public BSTInterface {
    ...
};

template <typename CKEY, typename OBJECT>
GCACHE{
  public:
   GCACHE(BSTInterface *bst); (A)
};
```

If `GCACHE` *does* need to access parts of `BST` that depend on template parameters, then you'll need to make `GCACHE` templated on those parameters as well:

```
template <typename CKEY, typename OBJECT, typename KEY, typename VALUE>
GCACHE{
  public:
   GCACHE(BST<KEY, VALUE> *bst); (A)
};
```

By the way, in general such a circular dependency between classes creates tight coupling and might indicate a design issue. Why would a "generic cache" need to know about the existence of a binary search tree? Or, if the cache is *implemented* as a tree, why would the tree implementation need to know about the existence of the cache?

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I think I'll follow the abstract class interface approach. GCACHE is Generic in the sense that it's able to cache every pair of (KEY,VALUE). the BST pointer is needed by GCACHE in order to retrieve the ofstream object uses to serialize the BST to disk.

Comment: If it needs only an `ofstream`, pass only the `ofstream`, either to the ctor or to the serialization function.

Comment: Thanks again Thomas, but the ofstream is not enough because I need to use a BST method to save the cached items in the correct format recognized by the BST class and I do not want to duplicate the code that does that.